# jsp:forward tag forwards to Struts 2 action

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, struts2, forward

I am migrating a Struts application to Struts 2. It was developed by Struts 1.2 four years ago.

**My question is:**

In my JSP, there is such a statement:

```
<jsp:forward page="/a.do" />
```

It works well in Struts 1, but does not work in Struts 2, it tells me HTTP 404 error when I was  accessing this JSP file.

However, if I access to `http://localhost:8080/shell/a.do`, it works well.

I wonder the reason, is it because the forward action cannot be caught by the Struts 2 filter? (`org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`)

So the forward cannot be dispatched to the Struts 2 action?

There are many forwards in my application, if forwards cannot work in Struts 2, does it the only solution to use redirect instead of forward?

Actually this question is based on my analysis, the original job is show welcome page of the site. If I use `jsp:forward` forwards to `a.do`, it doesn't work.

And I followed Roman's advice, use `result` instead of forward. So the question now is how to configure the default action for the entire application?

I tried `<default-action-ref name="a"/>`, but it works only for unmapped actions, for example `http://localhost:8080/shell2/(some-unmapped-action).do`, it goes to the default action. But it does not work if I do not specify the `".do"`.

Of course this can be done with url-rewrite, but I don't want to use this approach.

Comment: Hello all, I think this question can be closed, because only if I added `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher><dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher><dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` in my web.xml for the struts2 filter, this issue can be fixed. FYI.

Answer (score 4):

Include the struts tag library

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

and u can simply write in ur jsp page to forword to some action

```
<s:action name="YourAction" namespace="/PackageNamespace" executeResult="true" />
```

Comment: Why cannot we use plain html instead of struts2. is there any other avantage more than mentioning as directly <a href='/action path' > YourAction</a>

Answer (score 1):

The concept of `forward` from Struts 1 moved to concept of [dispatcher result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/dispatcher-result.html). You have to remove all `forward`s from your application and create `result`s instead.

Comment: "You have to remove all forwards from your application and create results instead." This is a great pointer! However, the real problem of mine is when I type in http://localhost:8080/shell2, I mean to go to the home page, so in my welcom.jsp file (configured in web.xml, welcome-file-list), the request can be forwarded to a struts 1 action. But  it cannot be done in struts 2. What I want to do is just a forwarding to home.do (a struts 2 action). Is it possible? Approaches I have tried as follow: 1. <default-action-ref name="home"/>, failed, this just matches the URL does not exist;

Comment: 2. <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/> this works, but all of the urls do not exist will go to home page, this is not what I want to see. I want to get is just a default HOME action. Is it possible in struts 2? Thank very much again!

Comment: the default action is that one that references to the action to handle requests where no mapping for the action found in the package. If you want to map "/shell" to the action that forward to "/home" you can use in the package with `namespace="/"` do `<action name="shell2"><result>/home</result></action>`

Comment: Thanks, Roman. I tried your suggestion, failed. To make things clear, I'd say, shell2 is my application name.  here is my struts.xml: `<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
  <action name="shell2"><result>/home</result>
  </action>
  <action name="home"
            class="com.broadvision.webflow.action.Struts2Action">  
   <param name="pack">&packName;</param>
            <param name="flow">&xflowDir;/{1}.xflow</param>
            <param name="loginRequired">false</param>
            <result name="success" type="redirect">/x3.jsp</result>
  </action>
 </package>`